# Thresholding for NDSI in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to apply thresholding on MODIS NDSI. My goal is the Yearly NDSI images.
For both Yearly and Monthly images, NDSI should move between -1 to 1, considering as a threshold value of 0.1, we should end having values between 0.1 to 1. But I'm not able to do it or I'm doing something wrong in my code.

```
var dataCollection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')

var maskedW21 = function(image) {
  var NDSI = dataCollection.select(['NDSI_Snow_Cover']);
  var maskNDSI = NDSI.lte(1).and(NDSI.gte(0.1));

  
  var mask = maskNDSI.updateMask(maskNDSI)
  .rename('mask');
  return image.addBands(mask)
  .updateMask(mask);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to `map` the `maskedW21` to the `dataCollection`. The only changes I made to the original script was changing `dataCollection` to `èe.Image(image)`, removing an extra `updateMask` and changing the threshold values. If you consult the bands' information of the collection, the 'NDSI_Snow_Cover' band takes values from 0 to 100, so I assumed that this is in a percentage scale and this transformed 1 to 100 and 0.1 to 10.

```
var maskedW21 = function(image) {
  var NDSI = ee.Image(image).select(['NDSI_Snow_Cover']);
  var maskNDSI = NDSI.lte(100).and(NDSI.gte(10));
  
  var mask = NDSI.updateMask(maskNDSI)
                 .rename('mask');
  return image.addBands(mask)
};

var resul = dataCollection.map(maskedW21);

// Check first image
Map.addLayer(resul.first(), {bands: 'mask'}, 'mask')
```

Comment: But I want to get collection in range of 0.1 to 1 so that I can take monthly mean for all yearly images

Comment: You can just divide NDSI by 100 using `NDSI.divide(100)` and then change the thresholds used to define the maskNDSI to 1 and 0.1.